# 02 4Runner with P0500 code

Tags: troubleshooting

Looks like this topic has been well covered but what I’m trying to figure out is how it happened. I put a new radiator in the truck and when I started it back up the dash lights came on brake, vsc, trac, abs, and now check engine. Does the speed sensor harness run anywhere near the radiator? Is it possible I disconnected or severed the wire? Would get coolant on the sensor somehow make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Probably accidentally disconnected it. The speed sensor is on the transmission output shaft.

Symptoms of P0500 code:

```
Loss of anti-lock brakes with light on dash being lit.
Speedometer may not read accurately 
Automatic transmission may shift erratically
```

Possible causes:

```
 Vehicle speed sensor not reading due to bad or missing connection 
 PCM not configured for size of tires.
```